# Why do I keep getting "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning" when running test with Selenium-webdriver?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I'm trying to implement Selenium tests with and without mocha on my frontend, on my app built i React. But I keep getting error. The mocha runs so there is something wrong with Selenium?

On a MacOS with versions:

```
"mocha": "^6.2.2",
"selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.5"
"geckodriver": "^1.19.1",
"safari": "0.0.1"
```

This is just the start, a really simple test to return the title of the app.

The app is up and running on `http://localhost:3000/`

I've tried different browsers; firefox and safari. 
They all open, but they all (eventually) return same error.

Running the test in test/src `node SimpleTest.js`

This is SimpleTest.js

```
var webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
const serverUri = "http://localhost:3000";

var browser = new webdriver.Builder()
    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox())
    .build();

browser.get(serverUri);

browser.getTitle()
    .then(function (title) {
        console.log("The title", title);
    });

browser.quit();
```

I expected output

```
$ node SimpleTest.js 
The title Me-Me-Me
```

But I got

```
$ node SimpleTest.js 
The title 
(node:1582) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchSessionError: Tried to run command without establishing a connection
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/$HOME/jsramverk/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:550:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/$HOME/jsramverk/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:563:13)
    at Executor.execute (//$HOME/jsramverk/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:489:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:1582) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:1582) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**SOLVED**
I had too many asyncronic code running syncronic.

```
const { Builder } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const Firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
require('geckodriver');
const serverUri = "http://localhost:3000/#";
let browser;

async function main() {
    const builder = new Builder().forBrowser('firefox');
    builder.setFirefoxOptions(new Firefox.Options().headless());

    browser = await builder.build();
    await browser.get(serverUri);

    try {
        const title = await browser.getTitle();
        console.log(title);
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log("Something went wrong", ex.message);
    } finally {
        await browser.quit();
    }

}

main().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: try `browser.close()` before `browser.quit()`

Comment: @Reez0 thanks, tried that but it didn't help. I changed the question because I solved it with captureing all and using async await.